# Multiplexer with enable at a karnaugh map

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, boolean-algebra

We have multiplexer 2->1 with reverse enable:

(sorry for the child-like graphics)

[image]

the function table is the following

e  c  Y

---

1   X   0

0   0   x0

0   1   x1

I tried to make a karnaugh map, but I don't know if I have to put the enable at it. So it went as something like this:

[image]

with the result being y = e'c'x0 + e'cx1

Did I do the map wrong?
Should I exclude the e from it?

Comment: Yes you should exclude the E from it. And the answer seems right that way. Y= E' * ((C' * X0) + (C * X1))

Comment: but it I exclude it,put the x1x0 on the x axis and c on the y axis, then the answer is x1c + x0c', not the same as before.

Comment: then you have to mode the e on the y axis as well and it should be the same. but then you have to make horizontal groups

Comment: if I do that, then what is the difference? It seems like I shouldn't exclude the E at all.

Comment: I think your map is correct as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E is the enable so if is exclude or include the Result will be same. And chart is shown below [image]

Now if you put K Map for this you find that answer  as 
   Y = C'X0 + CX1